Unable to import trax
I was trying to import Trax on Jupyter Notebook, and it gave me an error message.
I am running the Python 3.11 version.
installed trax using the "
pip install Trax 

command." All the dependent libraries JAX, NumPy, and TensorFlow are installed with this.
However, when I try to import trax, it gives the below error.
ValueError: no signature found for builtin function 
How to solve this error. What can I try to proceed.? Please help

There was an issue reported about this about a year ago here. You may wish to consult there and try some of the suggestions, such as to use gpu or edit Trax source code (see here.
